# Having a error in Ruby On Rails 1:1 association from Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the problem in ROR when I make the 1:1 association

I have the User model with user and password fields and I have the Profile model with name, age and user_id fields.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :User
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :profile
end
```

Income the information is through the ROR console

```
user = User.new
user.user = "XXXX"
user.pass = "12345"
user.save

profile = profile.new
profile.name = "XXXX"
profile.age = 20
profile.save
```

all good so far... but, when I make the association

```
user.profile = profile
```

gives me the error:

```
NameError: undefined local variable or method `profile' for main:Object
from (irb):5
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/application.rb:185:in `block in serve'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `fork'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `serve'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-1.6.2/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from
```

---

And the schema.db is:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20160219230003) do

  create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "age"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "user"
    t.string   "pass"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

end
```

---

Any solution to this problem?

I have ruby 2.3.0p0 and Rails 4.2.5

Thank!

Comment: Could you update your post with the current `schema.rb`?

Comment: I update my post, thank!

Answer (score 2):

```
profile = profile.new # <-- Error here
profile.name = "XXXX"
profile.age = 20
profile.save
```

The exception said:

> NameError: undefined local variable or method `profile' for
>   main:Object

`main:Object` is your console, and profile is undefined, it should be:

```
profile = Profile.new
```

Comment: I don't have error in this process, is a mistake of translate (I translate from Spanish to English)

Comment: I'm not sure but this is what was described in the exception

Comment: Thank for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
user = User.new
user.user = "..."
user.pass = "1234"
user.profile = Profile.new
user.profile.name = "..."
user.profile.age = 20
user.save
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I finally fix :)